# registro de origem inexistente. Como contornar? Chave Estrangeira

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho um campo em uma **tabela** de `celulas` que pede o *numero* da `celula` que a deu *origem*.

***Exemplo***:  Temos a **tabela** `celulas`:

```
idCelula,
nome,
etc ...
origem
```

Essa *origem* faz **referencia** ao `idCelula` da **célula** que a criou (*célula originando novas células*).

Acontece que `origem` é *chave estrangeira* **referenciando** `idCelula`.

***O problema***: Quando formos cadastrar a primeira célula, como não existe ainda uma **origem**, haverá um *problema na gravação* dela no **MySQL**.

Existe alguma *clausula* `case` por exemplo para contornar esse *problema*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Caso exista, retire a restrição **not null** do campo origem, assim caso uma célula não tenha "origem", ela pode ser inserida no banco sem problemas.

Comment: pois é. era isso que eu não gostaria. retirar o NOT NULL. Mas vai ser o mais viável!

Comment: Tenta controlar a inserção por meio de Stored Procedure, se for a primeira inserção permite inserir sem origem, caso o contrário, não permite.

Comment: boa, mas... como se faz isso?

Answer (score 1):

Há algumas opções. Todas têm vantagens e desvantagens:

1. você pode retirar a restrição NOT NULL do campo origem. Caso queira simular NOT NULL nos outros registros, forçando-os a incluírem uma origem, você pode usar recursos do banco de dados para isso:

   - usando VIEW WITH CHECK OPTION: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522026/how-do-i-add-a-check-constraint-to-a-table
   - usando triggers: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9662/check-constraint-does-not-work
2. você pode manter o NOT NULL e cada célula "principal" se auto-referenciaria; por exemplo, a célula com `idCelula = 1`, também teria `origem = 1`. Não é muito bonito em termos de modelagem, já que para valores desconhecidos é recomendado utilizar NULL.

```
   idCelula  origem  nome
   1         1       Principal 1
   2         1         Segundo nível 1
   3         2           Terceiro nível 1
   4         4       Principal 2
   5         4         Segundo nível 2
   6         5           Terceiro nível 2
```

Comment: O problema aqui é que uma célula nunca sai dela mesma pois ela ainda não existe.
Sempre precisará de outra célula como origem.

Comment: @CarlosRocha, é uma questão de convenção. Não existe uma modelagem perfeita para todos os casos. Você pode convencionar que a célula com `origem = NULL` é uma "original", você pode convencionar que a célula com `origem = idCelula` é uma "original", ou você pode encontrar uma outra regra para identificar as células "originais", como por exemplo incluir um campo com o nível da célula na hierarquia (0, 1, 2, 3, etc), e as células com nível 0 seriam as "originais", ou você pode incluir uma célula com `idCelula=0` e chamá-la de "original", etc etc etc. Cada opção tem suas vantagens e desvantagens.